# out of memory kernel crash

Tags: linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I am facing an issue on my system related to the out of memory (OOM) error. Under this condition, the oom kill utility of the linux kills a process (called "the bad process") using a specific algorithm to free up the space.
I want to print the memory, process stats just before this condition happens.

mm/oom_kill.c contains the function out_of_memory(). I wanted to print my stats just before this function moves ahead with the killing of "the bad process". For this i wrote the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to print process related info

echo "Vmstat " > OOM_memresults
vmstat >> OOM_memresults
echo >> OOM_memresults
echo "SLABINFO" >> OOM_memresults
cat /proc/slabinfo >> OOM_memresults 
echo >> OOM_memresults
echo "Status of process getting killed" >> OOM_memresults
cat /proc/$1/status >> OOM_memresults
```

Now the problem i am facing is to find a way to call this script from the kernel code.

I cannot use system("scriptname") as system function is not available in linux kernel, neither we can use exec and its variants.

Any ideas how i can call this script from the kernel code or any other way i can print the process, memory related info at any instant from the kernel code. 
The "current" function gives the information about the currently running process and its task_struct but its very difficult to pull any useful info out of it.

Comment: When it is needed to execute a user-space process from the kernel, [user-mode helper API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html) could be helpful. However, I cannot predict if the script will actually does its job when OOM killer is active. Still, may be worth trying.

Comment: yes you are right. I tried running this script somehow during OOM condition. It doesn't work.